# check if a list contains 4 elements of the same value

Tags: python, list-comparison

So I'm stuck on a newbie problem once more :D

I'm trying to mash together a text based game of go-fish against the computer.

Ok so 1 card is actually a tuple of elements from two lists.

```
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spade', 'Hearts']
ranks = [None, 'ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
```

Then that is added to a deck and shuffled and whatnot and then dealt into hands. (got most of it from the book thinkpython i think. Learned a lot about class structure and inheritance in the process.)

So one hand might look like this

```
['Clubs 2', 'Diamonds king', 'Diamonds 2', 'Spades 2', 'Hearts 2']
```

As you can see that hand contains four of the same rank so that's 1 point for the player.
But how would I check if the hand contains four instances of any item in the ranks list?
Do I have to iterate through each item in the list or there some clean and simple way to it?

---

**EDIT**
Thanks a lot for all the answers guys.  :D
But I'm getting an attribute error when I try to use 'split' on the items in the hand.
Guess I should have posted more of the code I'm running.

Full code and traceback here
http://pastebin.com/TwHkrbED

Is there something wrong with how the methods are defined in Card?
I've been hacking around for hours trying to make it work, but no luck.

**EDIT2**
Made some changes to the deck generating part. Now the whole deck is a list of tuples and a lot less code.

```
thedeck=[]
class Deckofcards:
    suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', 
        '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    def __init__(self):
        for i in self.suits:
            for a in self.ranks:
                thedeck.append((i, a))
```

Seems like the other way was overly complicated, but idk. I'll see how it goes tomorrow, adding the actual game parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might suggest a slight refactoring:  Represent each card in a hand as a tuple of `(rank, suit)`.  So your example hand would be:

```
hand = [('2', 'Clubs'),
        ('king', 'Diamonds'),
        ('2', 'Diamonds'),
        ('2', 'Spades'),
        ('2', 'Hearts')]
```

Then I'd suggest a couple of auxiliary functions to help you determine the value of a hand:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_counts(hand):
    """Returns a dict mapping card ranks to counts in the given hand."""
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for rank, suit in hand:
        counts[rank] += 1
    return counts

def get_points(hand):
    """Returns the number of points (ie, ranks with all 4 cards) in the given
    hand."""
    return sum(1 for count in get_counts(hand).itervalues() if count == 4)
```

**Edit:** Switched to using `sum` in the `get_points` function, which seems clearer to me.

Working with these functions and the example hand you gave, you get output like so:

```
>>> get_counts(hand)
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'king': 1, '2': 4})

>>> get_points(hand)
1
```

Comment: From Python 2.7, you could do it even easier with `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
x = ['Clubs 2', 'Diamonds king', 'Diamonds 2', 'Spades 2', 'Hearts 2']
ranks = [i.split()[1] for i in x]
fourofakind = any(ranks.count(i)==4 for i in set(ranks))
```

`fourofakind` is then True if there are four cards of the same rank in the hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an extended kind of functionality:

```
hand = ['Clubs 2', 'Diamonds king', 'Diamonds 2', 'Spades 2', 'Hearts 2']
hand_ranks = [i.split()[1] for i in x]
fourofakind = {}
for i in set(hand_ranks):
    fourofakind[i] = (hand_ranks.count(i) == 4)
```

Would give you a dict() mapping card rank (of cards in the hand) to whether you have 4 of that rank.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more general than Justin's:

```
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spade', 'Hearts']
ranks = [None, 'ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', \
'8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']

hand = ['Clubs 2', 'Diamonds king', 'Diamonds 2', 'Spades 2', 'Hearts king']
rankshand = [i.split()[1] for i in hand]

fourofakind = [hr for hr in ranks if rankshand.count(hr)==4]
threeofakind = [hr for hr in ranks if rankshand.count(hr)==3]
pair = [hr for hr in ranks if rankshand.count(hr)==2]

fourofakind
[]
threeofakind
['2']
pair
['king']
```

With the ability to see which rank has the set.

Answer (score 0):

The new built-in `Counter` class added in Python 2.7 to the standard library `collections` module makes this fairly easy.

```
suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spade', 'Hearts']
ranks = [None, 'ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
         '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
hand = ['Clubs 2', 'Diamonds king', 'Diamonds 2', 'Spades 2', 'Hearts 2']

from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(card.split()[1] for card in hand)
four_of_a_kind = [rank for rank,count in counts.iteritems() if count == 4]
print 'four_of_a_kind:', four_of_a_kind
# four_of_a_kind: ['2']
```